# Cross Compile OpenSSL

Tags: cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling OpenSSL for a PPC target. Compilation works fine and I can run OpenSSL on my target, however when I try to run one of the OpenSSL engines I get an error of engine directory.

The main problem is that when I build this I use `--prefix=/$PWD/usr --openssldir=$PWD/usr/local/ssl` but my target wants the files in `/usr/*`. I can only build OpenSSL with absolute paths but I don't want to move over my entire `/usr` path. Is there a way to change how OpenSSL searches for `engines/libs/etc`? Maybe I should be configuring this differently?

Edit: Using DESTDIR when running make install solved this issue

Answer (score -1):

The OpenSSL wiki says to set the same path for both of those params.

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#PREFIX_and_OPENSSLDIR

-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib will set the runtime link to the library

I recently wrote a post describing how to install it in a custom location. Might help you:

https://chrisbebek.com/blog/?p=34

Comment: Please don't just post the link, include the details here.